# M- 15 Peak of 1-pentene in EI-MS

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

This is the spectrum of 1-pentene.

[image]

And my professor says that the peak M-15 (55) came from this process:

[image]

But how this is possible, when I tried to prove through mechanism, no one situation match with it.

I tried these:

[image]

How can this CH3 peak exist with my professor process?

Comment: You know you can just cut the bond on the other end? I could see issues with other peaks, but this one...

Comment: Yes, I know, however, how does my professor find this peak (M-15) by his mechanics?

Comment: You don't need any mechanism for such elementary thing in MS. If you really need it for some reason, you could write there's a half bond (1 electron instead of 2) instead of any you want to break and make a fishing hook from it to the atom that you want to wind up as a radical.

Comment: That's for single bond, why would you try breaking double?

Comment: In an ionization, the electron in a pi bond is more accessible to leave than the electron in a sigma bond. The second picture is schema that my professor showed us. In this picture, the CH3 leave from sp2 carbon and not from other side.

Comment: Maybe if it was chemical ionisation then it would be an issue, but in MS you get cation radicals that are so excited that they break apart from surplus energy, and then break again! You're prof. seems to be confusing for no good reason.

Comment: Note that according to the second picture, the unique group that can be leave when the bond is break, is the CH2..

Comment: In the third picture, I put possibility, and no one they show a CH3 group leaving when the bond between carbons that before had pi electron is broken by ionization.

Comment: If the product is written exactly as stated on your answer, it cannot be true, as the ion depicted has m/z 57 and not 55. m/z 55 is a methyl-allyl cation, and thus has a double bond.